# Phoenix framework match different pattern on route to different controller

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I need to match different patterns on routes to different controller.

Example: to match `http://localhost:4000/<_ANY_THING_>` to `PageController@index`, I do:

```
get "/:page", PageController, :show
```

Now, I need to add another route that only match to following pattern:

> http://localhost:4000/@<_ANY_THING_>

That should match to `UserController@profile`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing different for a route containing an `@`:

```
get "/@:user", UserController, :profile
```

Just be sure to put this above anything else that has the potential to match (such as the catch all route in your example.)